# In a commit message, interactively get the github issue on "Fixes #"

Tags: helm, completion

I am jealous about a SublimeText plugin:

[image: get github issue interactively]

This plugin finds the github issues when you are in a commit message and you type a dash.

I didn't find an equivalent for Emacs so I decided that was a good exercise.

I found the pieces in about an hour but I've got difficulties finishing it, so I thought I might as well ask for help :)

What I can do:

- find the github issues, with https://github.com/inkel/github-issues.el which isn't in melpa
- fire helm
- fire helm when one types "Fixes #"

But I have to deal with some corner cases (repository not found, there is no issues, the github api rate limit is reached), I want to isolate the functions that call github but then my helm source doesn't work any more (this is the actual bug that I left for you). Also, how to define the helm source so that it doesn't call github when evaluating the whole buffer ? see

```
(helm :sources '(issues-helm-source))
```

So I'd enjoy very much to have reviews by experienced elisp developers. Thanks !

https://gitlab.com/emacs-stuff/git-commit-insert-issue

Comment: Regarding the fact that `github-issues` is on Melpa: `gh.el` is on Melpa, you may or may not prefer it.

Comment: Regarding the actual question: You spend most of the question explaining your motivation (which is very motivating, I agree) but then you dump a single line of code and ask "why doesn't it work?". Not to mention the title is completely different from the question you're trying to ask. **This is a helm question**. Put more focus on the actual problem you had. **What were you doing before you "isolate the functions"? Did that work? What did you change that made it stop working?**

Comment: I shouldn't have dumped the line of code then. True that I have a pb with it and helm, but I am more asking for (dreaming of :) ) a global code review.

Comment: I'll try to be more explicit with the helm question quickly. As for `gh.el`, I played a bit with it with no success before I found `github-issues`. I still can change it later on.

Comment: So, 2 things: I fixed the blocking bug so this snippet is usuable. Still, the `github-issues` dependency isn't on MELPA, its author didn't touch it for years and `gh.el` isn't appealling at all either: https://github.com/sigma/gh.el/issues/36

Comment: (for myself) about `gh.el`, see also those words by magit's maintainer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001651/most-developed-magit-github-extension-for-emacs-for-pull-requests

Comment: If you want to try doing the github thing manually, check out the paradox-github.el file inside the Paradox package. The function at the very end of the file essentially performs any github request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I finished this package: https://gitlab.com/emacs-stuff/git-commit-insert-issue

[image: fetch the issue in the commit message]

It's in MELPA, so to install it: `M-x package-install RET git-commit-insert-issue`.

It gives a minor mode and an interactive function to get issues. Github and Gitlab. Gitlab for private repos also.

(Thanks for the tips above and the review of melpa maintainers)

(there are good remarks [on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/3o7mkt/type_fixes_and_find_the_github_issue_in_the_helm/) too)

Comment: Why not accept this answer?

Comment: oh indeed, I just accepted my answer :) thanks